# Facebook like box - width of content

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-likebox

Since Facebook changed their image-size, my facebook Like-Box is all messed up.
Pictures and text are way too wide.

Is there a way how I can change the width of the CONTENT of the like-box?
I'm using the iframe-version.

Code is:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?locale=it_IT&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FNautica-Nautilus%2F167411390055525&amp;width=300&amp;height=395&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color=%23FFFFFF&amp;stream=true&amp;force_wall=true&amp;header=false&amp;appId=167411390055525" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:395px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Site is this one: http://tinyurl.com/cy9d3mz

Comment: Could you be more specific what you refer to by **content**?

Comment: The content of the likebox.
If you have a look at my site (http://tinyurl.com/cy9d3mz) down right you can see, that the content of the likebox is too large. This is happening since some days ago, when facebook changed their picture sizes.

Comment: Do you mean too many posts? Or do you mean the actual image size?  Where it cuts the date?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that since all you are doing is essentially displaying Facebook objects in your site, Facebook would want to preserve their "look and feel" with regard to the content.

These things would include

- Font styles and sizes.
- Picture dimensions.
- Icons.
- Pagination techniques.

In any case, the width of the content is directly related to the iFrame wrapper that you put it in. This is how HTML content is supposed to behave.  You can specify the width parameter [in the same place you got your iFrame code you posted above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcdJg.png).

From a design point of view you might be better off displaying the like box across 2 columns of your 3 column layout.  After all, you are displaying a plugin with a lot of content.  You'll need to provide it with the necessary screen real-estate that it requires.

Comment: Facebook usually lets you change the dimensions. 
If anybody can tell me how to do it - I'd be VERY thankful. :)

Comment: Of course I tried to change the width of the frame. Content-width doesn't change though.

Comment: The content width will not change because of reasons I mentioned above.  What you will achieve is a more balanced plugin where the content does not contain unnecessary line breaks...

Comment: So from today on after the facebook-picture-change everybody has to suddenly use LARGE likeboxes, which won't fit into any 2-columns-sidebar? Can't imagine this would be Facebook's solution.

Comment: @san - [These](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4064038/customizing-facebook-like-box) [two](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4874755/fblike-box-custom-css) posts talk about custom css for Facebook plugins.  They deal with some old techniques but it may still work or you.

Comment: I've tried some css-styling. I saw I can style the box in many ways. However - the content and pictures just remain too wide. I haven't found a way how to reduce the width of the content inside the like-box.